# Using Selenium from within Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Is it possible to somehow run selenium from within Cloud Functions for Firebase?
I found solution for AWS lambda but couldn't find any solution which fits firebase.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After checking the depths of the internet, the answer is no. It's not supported at the moment. However one can submit a feature request and hope that firebase team will implement it.