# Can I use Selenium WebDriver with Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: firebase, selenium, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to build a solution with Selenium, can I use Firebase Functions to initialize and load webpages with Selenium?

I have found some resources that state no; however they don't give any source and they are 4 years old..:

- [Using Selenium from within Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45968756/using-selenium-from-within-cloud-functions-for-firebase)
- [Google Firebase Functions: webdriver.io get source code of a html-website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44130594/google-firebase-functions-webdriver-io-get-source-code-of-a-html-website)

How or where can I check if this is still the case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't currently use Python to run Selenium scripts in Google Cloud Functions. There's a Feature Request in the Public Issue Tracker currently open, that can be found [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/129757153).
For the Node.js runtime for your Cloud Functions, you could use [puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer) which includes headless Chrome. I found this [blog](https://rominirani.com/using-puppeteer-in-google-cloud-functions-809a14856e14) post that details a use-case.

Or if you are ready to trade Python for Cloud functions, we have other services like : App Engine Flex and Cloud Run where you can get it working in Python.

- [Python Headless Browser for GAE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51427118/15803365)
- [Python headless Chrome with Cloud Run](https://dev.to/googlecloud/using-headless-chrome-with-cloud-run-3fdp)

I also found this [GitHub link](https://github.com/ccorcos/gcloud-functions-selenium-boilerplate) which vouches to run selenium on Google Cloud Functions. If you're fine with a JavaScript/TypeScript example instead of Python, I recommend that you try this template. However, I have not tested this.

Comment: Just what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: No you can't open any sort of webpage (that is not just an API call) with firebase functions.

You can use Google Cloud Run to have selenium / cypress / spyder run. GCR achieves a similaresq result, that being it is serverless and scalable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use Selenium WebDriver with Google Cloud Functions in nodejs.

You will need an additional library chromium (https://github.com/dtolstyi/node-chromium). It will download chromium binary inside the node-modules. This is needed as chrome is not installed in cloud functions. You can refer the below code how to create the driver instance using the brinary.

```html
  const chromium = require('chromium');

export function createDriver() {

  const chromeOptions = new Options();
  chromeOptions.setChromeBinaryPath(chromium.path);
  chromeOptions.addArguments('--no-sandbox');
  chromeOptions.addArguments('--disable-dev-shm-usage'); // overcome limited resource problems
  if (headless) {
    chromeOptions.addArguments('headless');
  }

  const driver = new Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .setChromeOptions(chromeOptions)
    .build();

  return driver;
}
```

If you want to download a specific chromium version then you need to add below config in the .npmrc file.

`node_chromium_revision = 1002548`

You need to specify the chromium revision here. Chromium revisions can be found from here (https://registry.npmmirror.com/binary.html?path=chromium-browser-snapshots/Linux_x64/).